# Predicting an output with a different size than the input using a MLP model

Tags: keras-layer, mlp

I would like to use a MLP model for a regression problem. The goal is to use several input data to predict 1 output data. My input size is (7726, 7,  7) and want to predict and output data of size is (7726, 7).

I tried using dense layers but I can't get the output of the model to match the size of the data to predict.
Do you have any suggestion on how to do this with a MLP ?